# How to it manipulate JSON multi-dimensional arrays using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, multidimensional-array

How would you iterate over this JSON string after converting it to an object using jQuery to access the Color property?

```
[{"Puff":[{"Color":"Gray"},{"Color":"Blue"}]},{"Puff":[{"Color":"DarkRed"}]},{"Puff":[{"Color":"DarkBlue"},{"Color":"Yellow"}]}]
```

Comment: First of all you have to deserialize it to an array, then array[i].Puff[j].Color

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have used parseJSON to deserialize it but was keen on accessing the property using some sort of iteration code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array of objects, which all have a key named "Puff" which contains another array of objects.

```
$.each(x, function(i) {
    console.log(i);
    $.each(this.Puff, function() {
       console.log(this.Color);
    });
});

0
Gray
Blue
1
DarkRed
2
DarkBlue
Yellow
```

Comment: great answer, but is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @JoseVega: You should know better than to ask, Jose. ;)

Comment: When dealing with a larger input, I would suggest using my solution. http://jsperf.com/object-iteration-speed

Answer (score 2):

I would opt for non jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/xguyj/

```
var x = [{"Puff":[{"Color":"Gray"},{"Color":"Blue"}]},{"Puff":[{"Color":"DarkRed"}]},{"Puff":[{"Color":"DarkBlue"},{"Color":"Yellow"}]}];

for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    for(var t = 0; t < x[i].Puff.length; t++) {
         console.log(x[i].Puff[t].Color);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you already have jQuery in your project, which the OP does, why use the verbose for(;;) syntax and have to do x[i].Puff[t].length madness when you can just do $.each() and refer to things with `this`? I get not using jQuery for everything, but there's no reason to go old school for this. =P

Comment: If performance is not an issue, I would agree with your statement. In my case I like my application to run as lean and fast as humanly possible. http://jsperf.com/object-iteration-speed

Comment: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%." If you are looping through an amount of elements that makes the performance matter, you're probably doing something wrong anyways.

Comment: @PaoloBergantino can't argue with Donald Knuth, but my responsibility to the OP is to give him the best answer I can. I will let him decide whether looping over the elements is, as Donald Knuth would say, "the critical code"

Comment: It's ok Vega, I still love you. Let's just hug it out, ok?

Comment: How's that for a fast response time?

Answer (score 1):

```
yourObject[someIndex].Puff[someOtherIndex].Color
```